# Unable to create sections without clearline in R markdown

Tags: r, markdown

I am trying to use R markdown to create a pdf ouput from bunch of script. I have this:

```
cat(paste("## ","MTcars\n"))
print(ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl))+geom_point()
```

It looks like it is not creating the section called. New line ("\n") not working.

But when I do this:

```
cat(paste("## ","MTcars\n"))
cat("\\clearpage")
print(ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl))+geom_point()
```

it works. But it puts the image on another page, I need images to show up right after the section heading (MTcars). Any ideas how can do this? Any line breakers that woud work here?

Comment: This seems like a lot of work to put the heading through a code block. If it's fixed anyway, why not just put it before the block?

Comment: upgrading the packages fixed the problem cat("  \n") now works for line breaks.